# Extract Lat/Long data from the javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to extract Lat/Long values from the below mentioned array. Please help me.

```
var products = {"PolygonCords":"[[51.65040675460229,0.034332275390625],[51.613752957501,0.028839111328125],[51.61034179610213,0.1812744140625],[51.642737480428536,0.157928466796875]]"};
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for the solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Parse the json string using **[`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** and iterate over array using forEach

```js
var products = {
  "PolygonCords": "[[51.65040675460229,0.034332275390625],[51.613752957501,0.028839111328125],[51.61034179610213,0.1812744140625],[51.642737480428536,0.157928466796875]]"
};

JSON.parse(products.PolygonCords).forEach(function(v) {
  console.log(v[0], v[1])
})
```